# nested if statment with so many text conditions ERROR

Tags: arrays, excel, text, multiple-conditions

this is my data table

[image]

I'm writing this formula in openoffice not excel, that's why you will see ";" instead of ","

my questions is that I'm trying to put the currency of each country's capital name, and I did it but the thing is that I'm unable to make more than 42 conditions!!!!!

Is there another way or another formula can I use???

Here is the formula I did, and it's working

```
=IF(D3="AMSTERDAM";"EUR";IF(D3="FRANKFURT";"EUR";IF(D3="OSLO";"NOK";IF(D3="COPENHAGEN";"MULTI";IF(D3="ALICANTE";"EUR";IF(D3="BARCELONA";"EUR";IF(D3="BERLIN TXL";"EUR";IF(D3="VILNIUS";"EUR";IF(D3="BRUSSELS";"EUR";IF(D3="CATANIA";"EUR";IF(D3="DUSSELDORF";"EUR";IF(D3="FARO";"EUR";IF(D3="GRAN CANARIA";"EUR";IF(D3="HELSINKI";"EUR";IF(D3="MALAGA";"EUR";IF(D3="MUNICH";"EUR";IF(D3="PARIS CDG";"EUR";IF(D3="RIGA";"EUR";IF(D3="SANTA CRUZ PALMA";"EUR";IF(D3="SEVILLA";"EUR";IF(D3="TENERIFE";"EUR";IF(D3="BUDAPEST";"HUF";IF(D3="ANTALYA";"TRY";IF(D3="GAZIPASA";"TRY";IF(D3="ISTANBUL";"TRY";IF(D3="BERGEN";"NOK";IF(D3="STAVANGER";"NOK";IF(D3="STAVANGER VIA ESBJERG";"NOK";IF(D3="LONDON CITY";"GBP";IF(D3="LONDON LHR";"GBP";IF(D3="LONDON STN";"GBP";IF(D3="MANCHESTER";"GBP";IF(D3="FUERTEVENTURA";"ISK";IF(D3="LANZAROTE";"ISK";IF(D3="PORTO SANTO";"ISK";IF(D3="GLASGOW";"SCP";IF(D3="GDANSK";"PLN";IF(D3="CLUJ­NAPOCA";"RON";IF(D3="STOCKHOLM";"SEK";IF(D3="PRAGUE";"CZK";""))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Create a table with the country in one column and the currency in a second then use VLOOKUP()

Comment: could you say how please?, i have attached an image of my tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a table in another section of your spreadsheet then use `VLOOKUP` to match the currency to your country.

```
=VLOOKUP(D3;Currency_Table;2;FALSE}
```

Which is lookup `D3` in the table named `Currency_Table` and return the exact match (from `FALSE`) in the second column which will give you your currency.

Or if you want the formula to exist without dependency upon another table you could use something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(D3;{"AMSTERDAM"\,"EUR";"FRANKFURT"\,"EUR";"OSLO"\,"NOK"; etc...};2;FALSE}
```

NB: I've added an escape `\` before the comma because I'm assuming you are from a language area that uses `,` as a decimal by your language settings I'm assuming you'll need that in your array for that to work.

Comment: it is not working, it keeps giving an error 514, have you noted that i am using openoffice?

Comment: @Rahim he first one should definitely work if you've done the table properly. The second one may be variable because of different syntax

Comment: Haha, thanks for the accept a year later. That's diligent!